# Passando array simples com axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios, postman

Boa Noite.

Estou tentando replicar uma chamada de API que faço no postman no axios da minha aplicação em Vue.js.

No postman eu passo um token e no meu body JSON da chamada eu passo o seguinte array simples apra realizar o download de um arquivo xlsx.

```
url: http://10.100.100.165:9999/download/arquivo/nome.xlsx
body: [1000,9645,32,1023]
```

Isso no postman funciona normalmente, mas não consigo replicar no axios.

Ele ou desconsidera os meus headers ou desconsidera os body da minha mensagem. Esse array também não é parte de um objeto, é apenas o array por si só.

```
download({dispatch,commit, state}, payload){
      const token = Cookies.get("token");
      let array = [];
      payload.forEach(element => {
        array.push(element.id)
      });
      axios
        .get("/download/arquivo/nome.xlsx",
        array,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        }
        )
        .then(res => {
          this.forceFileDownload(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch('apiErrorsHandler', error);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Veja se isso funciona: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Comment: aonde eu passo o array com as minha informações nessa chamada?

Comment: GET não envia dados, somente outros verbos (POST, PUT). GET envia parâmetros na url. Aconselho dar uma pesquisada sobre os verbos HTTP e seu funcionamento.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.